# calling method before initializing the class member

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I am facing an error during  using service in android .I call an activity CallingScreenActivity which I call by intent and putting a number string to which I have make a call .
So what I did in CallingScreenActivity is first I initialize a class member like this

```
 private boolean serviceConnected = false;
  private ISipService service;
  private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

      @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
          service = ISipService.Stub.asInterface(arg1);
          try {
              // Log.d(THIS_FILE,
              // "Service started get real call info "+callInfo.getCallId());
              Log.e("onservice connected", "on service  connected");
              serviceConnected = true;

          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
          Log.e("service disconnected", "desconnected service ");
          serviceConnected = false;
      }
  };
```

then I have bind service in onCreate() like this :

```
 bindService(new Intent(this, SipService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and finally get number from intent and call a method :

```
  private void placeCallWithOption(String number) {
      if (service == null) {
          Log.e("servcie is null ", "service is null");
          return;
      }

      try {
          service.makeCallWithOptions(num, 1, null);
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Now my problem is every time I call this activity to make a call it calls method placeCallWithoutOption first and service connected later so every time it prints **service is null**  in method and return then **service is connected**  in  service connected method .
How should I manage this please help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this function `placeCallWithOption` inside `onServiceConnected`.

create variable in activity:

```
private String number;
```

and in `onCreate` of activity

```
number=getIntent().getStringExtra("<number_key>",null);
```

and in `onServiceConnected`

```
 @Override
  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
      service = ISipService.Stub.asInterface(arg1);
      try {
          placeCallWithOption(number);
          // Log.d(THIS_FILE,
          // "Service started get real call info "+callInfo.getCallId());
          Log.e("onservice connected", "on service  connected");
          serviceConnected = true;

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Comment: is it correct way to use ??as in onserviceConnected actually I am initializing the class variable

Answer (score 1):

You can't call any method from service before it connected. So, you can:

1) add progress dialog "Connecting service..." on activity's start

2) hide progress dialog after service connected and call placeCallWithOption() from onServiceConnected() (not early).